# HTTP status code 404 but contents are loading perfectly fine

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am running a site, where I am trying my own slug mechanism.

here are my .htaccess file contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and in my **index.php** I have following code

```
$_REQUEST['action'] = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/");
...
if (!empty( $_REQUEST['action'] )) {

    $action = explode("/", $_REQUEST['action']);
    $slug = $action[0];
    $pageName = $slug.".php";

    if (file_exists($pageName)) {
        require_once $pageName; // 404 status code
    }
    else {
        echo 'Your page is not found'; // 200 status code
    }
} else {
    require_once 'welcome.php';
}
```

now how it will work is

```
/school will be mapped on school.php

/mobile will be mapped on mobile.php

/about will be mapped on about.php
```

apparently this work perfectly fine, contents are loaded fine, but issue with `HTTP status code` which is **404**

on the other hand if I type some thing random like

`/some-thing-random` it shows this line `echo 'Your page is not found';` with **200 status** code (please note some-thing-random.php does not exist)

**What strangely worked for me** is as follows, I just added following line in `.htaccess` file and its working fine now with 200 message

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

for all those concerned about `manually` setting header: I had not. and it should not, all sort of urls will be intercepted by index.php, at least this is what my understaing is about my .htaccess file

one more strange thing is that might help you to respond to my question is
let say 
if url is as follows
`www.mysite.com/about` and if rename file `about.php` as `xabout.php` and then just perform following

```
$fileName = 'x'.$slug.'.php';
require_once($fileName);
```

it works fine

Now my question is **what on earth is happning?** can any one **please explain** this to me (also note that I am using GoDaddy hosting)

Comment: I don't see how this could send anything but 200 (since the code doesn't set any response code at all), regardless if the page exists or not. Is this all the code or do you have some more that you're not showing us?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that's it. no other code. I have updated the question, please have a look. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To send a 404 code, it must be indicated in the header.

> header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

More infos on http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Comment: This isn't really a solution for the OP's actual problem though, since the OP gets 404 when it should be 200.

Comment: It may be a header 404 in included pages... And he also have the code 200 on a true '404'